# Android Webview loading slow for the first time

Tags: android, caching, webview

I have created a library to start an activity with a Webview.
I'm trying to load local HTML file which with an Iframe inside it Whenever I'm starting the activity, for first time it is taking approx. of 5 seconds to display iframe. The 2nd time it is taking approx. of 2 seconds to display.

How can i reduce load time, for the first load?

Here are the two java files respectively.

WebviewOverlay.java

```
String botUrl = "someurl";
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
myWebView.loadUrl(botUrl);
return myWebView;
```

WebviewActivity.java

```
wb = new WebviewOverlay();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, wb).commit();
```

Comment: For the first time, the whole webView is being loaded without the cache. The second time its loading from the cache as well hence the lower loading times .

Comment: Is there anything we can do like preload cache @Narendra_Nath

Comment: Sure. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

This one is not anything to do with Android, web page has lot of data and or may be high resolution images which taking time or any scripts on the page which taking time while loading

Answer (score 1):

You can use precaching to speed up the webpage load.

1. Load data(HTML) from the server and save it to a text file in our device memory.
2. Start a coroutine to load the webpage and store in local storage
3. Create a new activity in which we will create a webview which will be used to load this cached webpage.
4. Change some settings of our webview to enable support for javascript, domstorage, database etc.
5. Attach webclient to our webview
6. Load our previously created file which contains all our HTML cached and load it to the webview

Here's a Github repo that does exactly what you want it to do.

https://github.com/iambaljeet/WebViewPreCache

Answer (score 0):

Try using optimized images in your Webpage. Resize it from mspaint